# Search Error Appears on Blank Searches

Tags: templating, search

> Impossible to invoke a method ("getUrl") on a null variable

That's the error message generated by a blank search and some searches.

Fuzzy search is enabled in `config/general.php`, and it works.  The search template is straight from the Craft CMS "search form" tutorial.

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.search(query).order('score') %}

<h2>Search Results for "{{ query }}"</h2>
{% if entries|length %}
    {% for post in entries %}
        <div class="box col-sm-3">
            <div class="post-box vertical clearfix">
                <a href="{{ post.url }}" class="image-link arrow-icon dark-overlay"><img src="{{ post.postImage.first().getUrl('thumbImage')}}" width="434" height="434" alt=""></a>
                <div class="extra-info">
                    <h5><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title}}</a></h5>
                    <p class="meta small">{{ post.postDate | date('F d, Y') }} <a href="#">Nicole</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>You search for "{{ query }}" didn't retun any results</p>
{% endif %}
```

`{{ post.postImage.first().getUrl('thumbImage')}}` works without error every place else.

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> {{ post.postImage.first().getUrl('thumbImage')}}

Whatever entry `post` is referencing for whatever search term you're using when you get the error, doesn't have any `postImage` assets selected.

So when you call `post.postImage.first()`, that returns `null` and you can't call `getUrl` on `null`.

You can either make `postImage` required and make sure that all existing entries have at least one asset selected, or guard against it in Twig via:

```
{% set image = post.postImage.first() %}

{% if image|length %}
    {{ image.getUrl('thumbImage') }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: So, `postImage` is a required field for every entry (post) in the `posts` section.  The null is being thrown by a specific search fragment - taken directly from an entry that has a `postImage`.   Searching `an` or `an/` throws a null even though they are in the body of the post.   Searching `an/apn` or `an/apn-`, which are still fragments, will output the post (image and all) in the search results.  So, what is it about `an` and `an/` that throws the null?

Comment: You should guard against it in twig (always). Even if you make it a required field, someone can delete the asset out from under you.

In this case, you are searching not only entries in the `post` section, but other entries as well. One of them is matching, and it doesn't have a `postImage`.